# Add animation when USer slide the button

Tags: xamarin.android, material-design, material-ui

I have use swipebutton by 2.0.0 and i want like this animation when user swipe the button and add white background on swipe button where he place the finger.
[image]

Here is my Code i dont know how to add the sliding white background

```
<RelativeLayout 
          android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#F8F9FA"
            android:gravity="center"        
        android:layout_gravity="center">

<View 
       android:background="#FF4C7485"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"      
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
<com.ebanx.swipebtn.SwipeButton
    android:id="@+id/swipeButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"        
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"   
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
    app:button_image_disabled="@drawable/check_circle_outline"
    app:button_image_enabled="@drawable/check_circle_outline"
    app:button_background="@drawable/swipe_button" 
    app:button_bottom_padding="18dp"
    app:button_left_padding="20dp"
    app:button_right_padding="20dp"
    app:button_top_padding="12dp"   
    app:inner_text="Send"
    app:inner_text_background="@drawable/round_button"
    app:inner_text_color="@android:color/white"
    app:inner_text_size="16sp"
    app:inner_text_top_padding="10dp"
      app:inner_text_left_padding="1dp"         
    app:inner_text_bottom_padding="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want us to for you

Comment: In my Swipe Button when i Swipe the background not change but in the above image when he slide the white background start covering the button...i want this type of swiping when he slide the white background start adding on swipe button

Comment: Did you check the GitHub of your custom control if this is available as an API or not?

Comment: i did't get about available for api?

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/ebanx/swipe-button) nuget package? This is an Android project written by java, how did you add it to your project?

Comment: yes im using this one

Comment: How did you add it to your project?

Comment: just installing plugin and use it

Comment: Xamarin android very similar with Android

Comment: When I try to install this plugin, I get an error says: `Package SwipeButton 2.0.0 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package SwipeButton 2.0.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)`, Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes You should right click on your project open properties>Android Menifest>and add target android version 6 or greater i have added 6.

Comment: i have Created My project in xamarin android

Comment: Mark Upvote if Salution work on your side

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me. The default target android  version is 8.0 on my side is greater than 6. Can you upload a project with this plugin for me so that I can check it?

Comment: Where i upload it.

Comment: You can upload to Github.